# Getting exception in JOhm in example code

Tags: java, exception, jedis

Yesterday tried to use `JOhm` library with `Jedis` to simplify my work and cache whole object, not just parts of it. And already from the beginning I was met with exception.

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" redis.clients.johm.JOhmException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.Long field User.id to java.lang.Integer
```

I looked for this exception in source of the project (created also an issue there about that) and found the place where it is thrown, but I don't know annotations well and don't understand code quite well for that reason.

Maybe someone encountered the same problem?

Comment: Could you provide the code that is generating that error?

Comment: I already submited it to Github, where project is located. https://github.com/xetorthio/johm/issues/44